# Codeigniter default controller issue on Godaddy linux hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf-protection

I'm using Godaddy linux hosting and I've deployed codeigniter source code on it. It is working absolutely fine on localhost. My default controller name is 'Welcome'.

1. When i try to login by pressing login button after entering
       username and password, without writing default controller name in
       the url then it says "The action you have requested is not allowed." in some locations it works fine.     Here is how i write
   url  'https://www.example.com'
2. When i write default controller name in the url, then enter username and password and then press login button. it works fine. Here is how i write
       https://www.example.com/Welcome
3. When i remove 'www' from
       base_url in config file, it works fine on some locations but don't
       work in some other locations.
   Here is my config file

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';

   $config['index_page'] = '';

   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

   $config['url_suffix'] = '';

   $config['language'] = 'english';

   $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

   $config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

   $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

   $config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;

   $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@';

   $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
   $config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
   $config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
   $config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

   $config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;

   $config['log_threshold'] = 0;

   $config['log_path'] = '';

   $config['log_file_extension'] = '';

   $config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
   $config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
   $config['error_views_path'] = '';
   $config['cache_path'] = '';
   $config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
   $config['encryption_key'] = '';
   $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
   $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
   $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
   $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
   $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

   $config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
   $config['cookie_domain']    = '';
   $config['cookie_path']      = '/';
   $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
   $config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

   $config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

   $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

   $config['csrf_protection'] = True;
   $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_snt_token';
   $config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_snt';
   $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
   $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
   $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();


   $config['compress_output'] = FALSE;


   $config['time_reference'] = 'local';


   $config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

   $config['proxy_ips'] = '';
   ```

I don't know where is am doing wrong. I want that it should work without even writing default controller name in the url. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to look at the Routes area / file - that dictates how users are moved around your app

Comment: there is nothing in route file except defaulter controller name

Comment: i think problem is with .htaccess file. you need to write rewrite rules and rewrite conditions.

Answer (score 0):

use htaccess code which is provide in CI_Docs [URL](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)